# How to display a local html file in Android?

Tags: java, android, html, xml, webview

I wanted to display a simple html page in a WebView in Android,
so I made an `assets` folder in main and put the `test.html` file,
but when I run the app, I get web page not available
This is my code

```
public class AndroidHTMLActivity extends Activity { 

    WebView myBrowser;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
        final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
         = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);

        myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");      

        myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///assets/test.html"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For accessing the asset folder you need to use `android_asset`.

Hence your code should be,

```
   myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
    = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);

   myBrowser.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");
```

Remove this and check READ Storage permission in your manifest